# Exceção lançada ao excluir registro utilizando o Entity Framework Core. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Ao tentar excluir registro das entidades "Pacientes" e "Médicos" é retornada uma exceção. O estranho é que para a entidade de "Agendamentos" tudo ocorre normalmente.

Segue a exceção:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Paciente'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for
>   {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry
>   entry)

Usarei o código da entidade "Paciente" como exemplo, mas ocorre da mesma forma para a outra entidade citada.

1. Form na view que envia a ação

   ```
   <form asp-action="Delete">
       <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
       <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
   </form>
   ```
2. Cógigo da Controller

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
   {

       var pacienteViewModel = _mapper.Map<PacienteViewModel>(await _pacientesRepository.ObterPorId(id));
       if (pacienteViewModel == null)
       {
           return NotFound(); 
       }

       return View(pacienteViewModel);
   }

   [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
   {
       var pacienteViewModel = _mapper.Map<PacienteViewModel>(await _pacientesRepository.ObterPorId(id));

       if (pacienteViewModel == null) return NotFound();

       await _pacientesRepository.Remover(id);
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   ```
3. Código na camada de acesso a dados (Comum a todos, está na classe abstrata herdada por todas as entidades)

   ```
   public virtual async Task Remover(Guid id)
   {
       DbSet.Remove(new TEntity { Id = id});
       await SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

**Lembrando que o processo ocorre normalmente para a entidade "Agendamento", já analisei o código e não enxergo nada de diferente.**

Comment: ao meu ver deve ter relação com esse new TEntity {Id = id}, você ta tentando criar uma entidade nova passando o mesmo id de uma ja existente

Comment: Sim, é o que da para entender da mensagem.
Porém já fiz testes para ver se poderia ser isso, mas nada resolveu.

Usei o Dispose(), setei um Guid Id vazio antes de acionar o EF Core através do Remover() mas nada disso adiantou

Comment: Mas porque você "cria" uma nova entidade para removê-la? Não seria o cado de encontrar o registro e excluir ele do contexto?

Comment: Pode passar um um desenho do modelo? Algum Enum nessas entidades? Como está a injeção do modelo?

Comment: Editei, André. 
Veja se é isso mesmo que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

O problema não está no momento em que tentamos excluir, e sim quando obtemos o objeto através do EF Core antes de exlcuir. 
O problema ocorre pois o EF Core não permite a alteração e exclusão de objetos mapeados pelo change tracking.

Segue a minha solução:

**Problema:**

```
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> ObterPorId(Guid id)
    {
        return await DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }
```

**Solução:**

```
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> ObterPorId(Guid id)
    {

        return await DbSet.AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstAsync(c => c.Id == id);
    }
```